# AWS API/Lambda POST capabilities

Tags: http, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to create a API/Lambda process which takes a comment and posts in into my RDS Aurora database.

- The comment field in the database is set as TEXT type
- The lambda function posts the comment to the database
- The API method is POST
- A mapping template has been set u to map the request body into the lambda function

All work perfectly until I start to try and post large comments. (A large paragraph, maybe 500 characters)

The body looks as follows:

```
{
   "comment":"long comment"
}
```

When I run it in Lambda, I can post massive comments, however when I try and do it through the API Gateway I get an error

```
Endpoint response body before transformations: {"stackTrace": [["/var/task/app.py", 38, "handler", "raise Exception('Internal Error: Unable to post the comment.')"]], "errorType": "Exception", "errorMessage": "Internal Error: Unable to post the comment."}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the test invoke feature on API Gateway console. From there, you can see the payload before transformed and after transformed. That might be a bit on debugging.